# Add Column to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, types, filter

I've followed Wordpress Plugin API/Action Reference/manage posts custom column to add a column on edit page to a Custom Post type. Following this reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column works when i have a custom post type named 'books' but if I have a custom post type named 'book-stores' this method doesn't work. It never works when I have a custom post type which name is in two words. Can someone help with this. Thank You.

**UPDATE:**
I resolved this problem. It was being caused because of Admin Columns plugin.

Comment: Please share some code. But my guess is you are using "-" instead of "_" in your function names. PHP has an issue with this

Answer (score 0):

The post type name/slug. Used for various queries for post type content.

Slugs should only contain **alphanumeric, latin characters. Underscores** should be used in place of spaces.

Comment: You've misunderstood the issue.  `book-stores` does _NOT_ contain a space.

Answer (score 0):

But it has a dash, which is disallowed. https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/why-is-underscore-permitted-in-the-post-type-but-dash-is-disallowed